# Incoming mail in rails, getting ID from subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm building a support system, that will need to accept incoming mail and create or update my "tickets" accordingly. So update if it exists, or create if none exists.

I need to get the ticket_id from the subject line, my ticket subjects usually look like this:

"Open [MySupport - #13 Management] Problem With Website"

Explanation:
Open - Ticket.status,
MySupport - Static test on each ticket subject,
13 - Ticket_id,
Management - Ticket.department,
Problem with website - Ticket.subject

So I'm using mailman for incoming mail, how do I strip out just the number 13 in this example to save it into a local ticket_id so i can check wether i need to update or create a ticket?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
subject = "Open [MySupport - #13 Management] Problem With Website"
```

Now do a simple regex:

```
subject.scan(/#(\d*)/)
# => [["13"]]
```

You can have a check like:

```
a = subject.scan(/#(\d*)/)
if a.size > 0
 ticket_id = a[0][0]
else
 ticket_id = nil
end
```

**NOTE**: I have assumed that the subject will always be in this pattern and in other case the subject won't contain "#". If that is not the case, you can make the regex more strict as per your requirement.